# Converting from Mootools to Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I have started to  convert a code on my site to jquery from mootols I would like to include jQuery instead of mootools and then write some functions I'm using in mootools to jQuery so I can use the exact same code. Some of the code I'm using I already converted is for example:

```
jQuery.fn.addEvent = jQuery.fn.bind;
```

However I'm having a hard time doing these:

```
$some_node.getElement('.class'); //where $some_node is an element like $(.selector);
$some_node.addClass('class');
$some_node.fireEvent('focus');
_node.setProperty('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('disabled');
$btn_node.removeProperty('disabled').removeClass('disabled');
```

Is there something out there for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `$some_node` is a jQuery object, then the function equivalent in jQuery would be

- `getElement('selector')` should be `find('selector').first()`, as `getElement` in Mootools seems to return the first element, thus `first` is used to reduce the `find` result array back down to one.
- `addClass('class')` is just... `addClass('class')`. Can't see why you would have trouble with this.
- `fireEvent('event')` should be `trigger('event')`
- `setProperty('attribute', 'value')` should be `attr('attribute', 'value')`
- `removeProperty('attribute')` should be `removeAttr('attribute')`

Of course there almost certainly are subtle differences between the functions in both languages, most of which I cannot point out as I am unfamiliar with Mootools.

Answer (score 0):

Surely the above would convert to:

```
$('.class').addClass('class');

$('.class').live("focus", function(e) {
     //Do something on focus
     //E.g. $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('disabled');
});
```

Or if you just wish to set the document focus on that element:

```
$('.class').focus();
```